# Is there a way to display on the doc that there are functions get called inside another in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

```
/**
 * This function will be get called inside the {@link myFunc1} function.
 */
const myFunc2 = function() {
   console.log('I got called!')
}

/**
 * This function will call the {@link myFunc2} function inside of it.
 */
function myFunc1() {
   myFunc2()
}
```

Is there any way to display on the documentation of the `myFunc1` function that there is the `myFunc2` function is get called inside?
What i mean is that whether i can display somethings like a list of functions that get called inside of a function, and then I can use the @link tag to link to the documentation of those functions, make the documentation become more useful.

Is it possible to do it? Hopefully you can tell me, thank you so much.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but generally speaking, the documentation should describe *what* are you doing not  *how* you are doing it.

Comment: It describes what the functions, classes, constructor, etc are doing. It doesn't show how I make functions calling others or the way that I write the math to make a function run, or something like that, right? Is that what you mean?

Comment: exactly. Documentation shouldn't explain the implementation details, but the interface of your API.

Comment: So I think I should just create documentation for the inner function instead of explain where did they get called. It’s a right way to write a good documentation, right? Thank you so much!